# How to get length of string from the smallest to the largest C#

Tags: c#, arrays, console, streamreader, string-length

At the bottom is the line readbyline from txt file and the words are split by space between them (`" "`) how do I sort and return the length from the smallest to the largest?

This is what I have now - click on the link:

[link to the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czrAr.png)

The code

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(textFile))
{
    using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(textFile))
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string words; 
        string[] line;

        while ((words = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            line = Regex.Split(words, " ");

            foreach (string line_1 in line)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line_1 + " " + line_1.Length);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            counter++;

            Console.WriteLine("Line[{1}]: {0}\n", words, counter);
        }

        file.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("File has [{0}] Lines.", counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should get into [LINQ](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/linq_objects.htm) (also Google it), especially `orderby`.

Comment: You can obtain an `IEnumerable` collection of elements using `from line in line_1 orderby line_1.Length select line_1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq and you will get Min and max length, like below.

```
var min = words.Split(' ').Min(s => s.Length);
var max = words.Split(' ').Max(s => s.Length);
```

If you need all words by Sorted then use below.

```
var sortedList = words.Split(' ').Select(s=>new {Word=s,WordLength=s.Length }).OrderBy(o=>o.WordLength);
```